# How to Diagnose sample ASP.NET/Cosmos Web App deployed to Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have forked the sample [PlanetaryDocs](https://github.com/JeremyLikness/PlanetaryDocs) ASP.NET Web app. This WebApp connects to my Cosmos DB (SQL/DocumentDB) and seems to run fine from Visual Studio via a Docker container... I have published it to the Azure Container Registry (ACR).

When I deploy to Azure App Service it gives me the URL and when I point my browser at it I see "Application Error, If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources" but clicking on the hyperlink (for the diagnostic resources) has no affect.

1. I tried restarting the app with the VS Code App Service extensions and looking at the logs for some error messages could find nothing helpful (only a few messages about no traces in the last 5 minutes and "the log streaming session has ended")... Perhaps the restart ends the log streaming session? How do I get logs of the restart?
2. So if the app runs from my dev machine because my dev machine's IP address is listed as one of the permitted external IP addresses in the Azure Portal (for my Cosmos DB config) that can access my cosmos DB, is this a (the?) problem? Do I have to add the IP address of the Azure App Service instance as one of the permitted external IP address? How do I do that? Perhaps I need to set up a virtual network?
3. Besides looking at the logs, are there any other debugging tools available? How can I get that hyperlink to work on the web page?

**Wed Jan 05, 2022 Update #1 (VS 2019):**

4. Wow! I love that UI for the VS 2019 Cloud explorer and I see it is not available for VS2022. Anyone know why they took it away?
5. So in the past I was able to use VS2019 to create a docker container (in release mode) and deploy it to Azure Kubernetes and attach with the VS2019 debugger to the Kubernetes Pod and somehow it was magically able to show me source code and allow me to single step! Is it possible or necessary to create a docker container in debug mode and deploy it to the Azure Web App and attach with the debugger? How do I create a debug mode docker container?
6. As per those great instructions, I was able attach the VS 2019 debugger but don't see anything from the stack trace -- even after pressing the pause (double vertical bars) button. Shucks... I see I have three running tasks and lots of threads but I cannot look at them. Am I doing something wrong? I tried clicking continue and pause several times hoping to get some clues but no luck.
7. Here are the logs from the `az.cmd webapp browse` command but I cannot find any clues in them either.

```
WARNING: 2022-01-05 22:51:44 PLANETARYDOCS GET / - 80 - 10.0.128.7 ReadyForRequest/1.0+(AppInit) - - xyz.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 377 417 15
WARNING: 2022-01-05 22:51:45 PLANETARYDOCS GET /DebugWarmUp X-ARR-LOG-ID=35910c0e-098c-430a-adb7-c91f1086599a 80 - 10.0.64.5 - - - xyz.azurewebsites.net 404 0 2 470 600 31
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:53:27  PID[21316] Verbose     SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:53:27  PID[21316] Verbose     SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:54:29  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:55:29  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:56:2
WARNING: 9  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:57:29  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:58:29  No new trace in the past 5 min(s).
WARNING: 2022-01-05T22:59:29  No new trace in the past 6 min(s).
WARNING: 2022-01-05T23:00:29  No new trace in the past 7 min(s).
```

**Wed Jan 05, 2022 Update #2 (Kudo):**

8. I followed HarshithaVeeramalla's instructions (thank you) and found some (raw) logs in the http/RawLogs directory. There was no application directory I could not find any logs or anything else interesting anywhere else. Logs looked like a lot of GET requests from a browser to get the favicon and other graphics mixed in with some AJAX/REST calls that I could not recognize...
9. The kudu/trace directory contained a lot of XML files and I could see from the file names that I restarted the web app today.
10. So let us assume that the problem is that I cannot connect to my azure cosmos DB, perhaps I have a typo in my cosmos end point.  There should be a C# stack trace somewhere (preferably with some nice line numbers of source code in it)... Is that something I could diagnose in Kudu? Where would I look?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have restricted access to cosmos via ips, and running it in a container in some cloud resource, and not added that ip.. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct... I don't know what the IP address is of my App Service instance and I don't know how to get it. (How do I get it for an ASP.NET 6 app?) The VSCode extension for App Service only supports SSH and debugging sessions for nodejs apps.

Comment: Go to the kudu site check the log file. Go to https://[your-WebApp].scm.azurewebsites.net/ , Debug console > CMD, go into D:\home\LogFiles\Application\`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Besides looking at the logs, are there any other debugging tools available? How can I get that hyperlink to work on the web page?

As [@Harshitha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16630207/harshithaveeramalla-mt) Suggested that logs can be viewed from kudu site as Go to the kudu site check the log file. Go to `https://[yourWebApp].scm.azurewebsites.net/` , Debug console > CMD, go into D:\home\LogFiles\Application.

To debug your application, connect from Visual Studio 2019 and it should all work without changing the portal settings.

1. Open Visual Studio and your project
2. Open Cloud Explorer  `View -> Cloud Explorer`  or  `ctrl+\, ctrl+x`
3. Find your App Service node in Cloud Explorer and select it
4. Choose  `Attach Debugger`  from the context menu or the actions pane.
   [image]
   If the Visual Studio is not displayed in the "**Classic**" Application settings screen, you will need to use the new Configuration menu, then choose the "**General Settings**" tab when the blade opens.
   [image]

Please find these [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-debug-azure-app-services-using-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio/) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of things I learned:

**Remote Debugging with the Visual Studio Debugger:**

If you abandon Docker and just deploy your application with the 2022 Visual Studio's publish feature (right click on the project in the solution view) to a windows (instead of linux) app service plan, you just deploy using Visual Studio 2022 and then look for the tiny "..." and click on that where you get a prompt to attach with the debugger...

**Turn On StdOut Logging**

When I tried looking at the Kudo and the Cloud Explorer log feature unique to VS 2019, I was not sure which logs I was looking at. For some strange reason standard output (stdout from the C# web app) logging is not turned on default. See [this bicep file for an example of turning on stdout logging](https://d3e6c31c-3d48-4749-acfd-94879dea8ea9). Alternatively, the portal.azure.com allows you to turn on logging. You can then get a great view of the output from stdout logs when you click on the "Log Stream" feature on the portal.

Comment: I found some more documentation on logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/configure-web-app-settings/5-enable-diagnostic-logging